# Install Ubuntu on external Disk

Tags: dual-boot

I need to have Ubuntu on my MacBook but I do not want to mess with my macOS. I tried to install Ubuntu on an external HDD but, after using it and restarting the system, Ubuntu loses everything.

How I can get Ubuntu up and running and recording my work sessions?

Comment: Can you [edit] the question to explain more about "Ubuntu loses everything"?

Answer (score 0):

I'm guessing that you have been running Ubuntu from a USB stick?
When you do that, I think you have the option to save on that USB drive, or don't save anything. You may have done the latter, or if you run it again, you will find what you did.

There are a few options if you want to keep MacOS:

- start the installer, choose install and see if you can choose : resize existing partition or anything like that : this will shrink the MacOS partition for you and install it next to it on the external hard disk
- start the installer and install on the external drive (assuming you boot from 1 usb stick and you have another for storage, or an external SATA drive enclosure for example)

In the first way, you can install GRUB on the main hard drive, in the second you could install it on the external one.

I hope this gives you some pointers on where to go, in any way, make a backup of important data before you start and lookup how to boot macOS from the recovery partition if you may need to restore. Good luck!